# What is it called to change the owner of a property?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm looking for a word which is used when you want to **change the owner** of a property to someone else. For instance how can I say that I changed the owner of my house to my brother? And I mean that the previous owner was me and the new one is my brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "I have transferred the ownership of the house to my brother" - or in more strictly legal parlance "I have transferred the house title to my brother".

Comment: "I have made over the house to my brother" can also be used.

Comment: @KateBunting - 'signed over' as well, at least in the UK, and 'put the house in my brother's name' also, although that might possibly imply an attempt to e.g. avoid taxes, claims for damages, etc.

Comment: People in the UK who become unable to care for themselves and need care provided by the local authority have any savings, and capital holdings, etc, assessed and have to pay a charge based on that (up to a maximum). The value of a house is considered to be 'capital'. Sometimes people think they can reduce or avoid charges by 'putting the house, savings, investments, etc, in someone else's name' (as a gift). Often a relative. But the authorities are wise to this,  classing it as 'wilful divestment', and the value thus divested may be included in any assessment. Also applies to bankrupt people.